# How to check address book against my application

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I need to check address book and if ;

- a person from address book is installed my app, user will be able to send a friend request,
- a person from address book is not installed my app, user will be able to send an sms to relevant person to install the app.

This is actually same as Snapchat. So, what is the proper way to implement it ? 
For instance, should I get phone number of the installer and record it to Users table in database ? Then when another user install the app, check all address book against Users table in DB and mark them application installed or not !

Maybe, there is an easy way to do it.  So, please help me and provide some sample code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use

CloudKit for the first question part:
`discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler` 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler:

You can get users that are also use your app.

For the second part, you can just use Address Book api I think to get all persons in the AB without your app.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

Address Book is deprecated (or will be), so take a look at this WWDC 2015 video Contacts framework: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-223/

Comment: Thank you, I will check all these documents.